# Cpu type/subtype in slice (arm64e.old) does not match fat header (arm64e)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using

```
pod 'SygicUIKit'
pod 'SygicMaps'
pod 'SygicMapsKit'
```

in my Swift project, while creating the build in Xcode 15.1, I am getting an error

> ld: Cpu type/subtype in slice (arm64e.old) does not match fat header
> (arm64e) in '/Pods/SygicMaps/SygicMaps.framework/SygicMaps'

Am I missing something?